# Read Chrome browsing history within extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I check if a certain link is found in Chrome's browsing history(on the computer that accesses the link) using JavaScript or jQuery? I am interested (if any) in the functions that I have to use. Also how can I get the date and time of the accessed link?

Comment: You should clarify that this question is about programming an extension and not a web page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Retrieving the users history from javascript launched *from a web page* is impossible due to obvious blatant security issues.

Retrieving the users history from javascript running *in an extension* is possible, but doing so requires elevated permissions that the user has to grant after being warned. In summary you are probably looking for the `chrome.history.getVisits()` function. You can find more information on how to access the history [using `chrome.history` here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html) and the resulting security [warnings given to the user here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nonono!  That cannot happen.  Unless you make a plugin, but I still doubt it.

This might be off topic but you might be interested in [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/#utm_campaign=en_us&utm_source=en-ha-na-sk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=analytics).

Comment: @Bogdan you didn't say that in your original question. That is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

this chrome extension allow you to use browser address bar to search keywords, which will automatically search against your browser history and give you suggestion

[Chrome webstore - history as bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-as-bookmark/mfbdcpljldfodjopfhbafaipgmfgalbl?hl=en-GB&authuser=0)

Answer (score -1):

This is just not possible with Chrome because of security. What you would have to do is use cookies and add to the cookie each page the user is on along with the time visited.

Problem with this it will only track a user on your site not others. Cookies are only suppose to hold small amounts of info not long tracks of what page your user has been on. Also a user can disable cookies...

Another way is maybe doing this serverside and tracking the users IP through your pages and keep a list of what pages your user is visiting.

Comment: Note this question was asking tagged abut chrome, not as website javascript. This is possible in the context of an extension.

Comment: The original question was very poorly written so edits did make the situation much clearer but the original was tagged google-chrome and talked about doing things from the computer not from a website.