# Any way to allow chrome://history-frame to load in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load chrome://history-frame into an iframe in my extensions page but it is giving:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome://history-frame/. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

I have tried adding the url to the permissions element in manifest.json as well as adding it as:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' chrome://history-frame; object-src 'self'"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can load this into an iframe?

Comment: I believe you can't, but maybe someone comes up with some clever workaround...

Comment: @ExpertSystem Worst case scenario is I open it up in another tab get what I want from DOM, then remove() the tab. Not very clean but will work for my purpose and I only need to do it once.

Comment: @click2install what if you [override the page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html)? Similar [bug still open.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=11854)

Comment: @JSuar that is what I am doing. I am trying to get access to the history mechanism for retreiving the entries for the default history page as they are only exposed within that page. Strangely enough, the default history page uses an iframe without issue, so obviously the security they apply to extensions is the issue. Lucky I am persistent :)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133550/1085891

Comment: @JSuar yes that is related to getting visits after your extension is installed. I am trying to query previous history so my extension is not limited to point in time of installation. Thank you.

Comment: More disappointing is that when visits from other devices are populated into the browser the extension is running on, the `onVisit` event is not fired, it is only fired for visits from that browser :( I will post on Google groups in an attempt to get some Google Chrome techs input.

Comment: @ExpertSystem if you want to copy your comment into an answer I will award it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions are not allowed to load origins with the `chrome://` scheme in an iframe (**[nor is it allowed](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script)** to white-list such origins in the CSP).